# Pass reference of main object to another object

Tags: javascript

I created this simplified version of some code I'm dealing with. I need to figure out how to pass a reference of an instantiated object to another object that has been created by this object. I can't get the reference to the main object "self" to be passed to the second object and actually be able to call a function on it. Hopefully the code will make it more clear:

```
var app = app || {};
(function (m, $, undefined) {

    m.Counter = function () {
        var self = this;
        var pub = {};

        pub.total = 0;

        pub.add = function () {
            pub.total++;
        };

        pub.subtract = function () {
            pub.total--;
        };

        pub.status = function () {
            console.log(pub.total);
        };

        pub.spawn = function () {
            var sp = new app.modules.Obj(self);
            return sp;
        };



        return pub;
    };

    m.Obj = function (counter) {
        var pub = {};

        pub.add = function () {
            counter.add();
        };

        return pub;
    };

}(app.modules = app.modules || {}));

var c = new app.modules.Counter();

c.add();
c.add();
c.add();
c.status();

d = c.spawn();
d.add();
c.status();
```

What I would want to have happen is that d.add() would increment the total of c. So the output would be 3 for the first c.status() call and then 4 for the output of the second c.status();

Comment: `add` is not a method of `self` or `this`, it's a method of `pub`. You'd have to pass `pub` to `app.modules.Obj`, since it's the public interface of your object. I'm not a big fan of this coding technique, because it can make things unintuitive, but that's only my personal opinion.

Comment: So what happens when you run the code and what did you expect to see happen?

Comment: @FelixKling how would you change this code to make it more intuitive - out of curiosity and desire to learn. thanks

Comment: @MattBurland I've edited my question to show the desired output at the bottom.

Comment: I would use a normal constructor function and add the methods to the prototype. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function and the following sections.